# Creating folder alias in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, alias, localization

I've got the following issue with both a Windows 7 and a Windows 10 installations in french.

Let's say I have a file located in my user's home drive: `c:\users\USER123\video.mov`.

For an unknown reason, one of my tool is maintaining a reference to that file under the **localized** name `c:\utilisateurs\USER123\video.mov`.

**However this fully localized name does not exist** (while the non-localized name exists).
And while, typing `c:\utilisateurs` in the Windows Explorer bar is redirecting to `c:\users`.

I was thinking of creating an alias in Windows 10. Either from `c:\utilisateurs\` to `c:\users\` or from `c:\utilisateurs\USER123\` to `c:\users\USER123\`.

Is this possible ? Anyother idea ?

Comment: Sounds like it’s already redirecting, if you type the path in file Explorer, and you are redirected.  Why does it matter that the application use the localization path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my first ideas was also using MKLINK /J. The first directory would be the "link" while the second directory would be the "target". The target should exist already, and the link creates a new link (shortcut).

However, if you do it like Señor CMasMas suggests, you will receive an error message: `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`
That's because you're trying to create a link named "*C:\users\USER123*", but that folder already exists, and it points to itself. You cannot have a directory point to 2 different locations. You can, however, try to create a link at *C:\utilisateurs\USER123* which points to *C:\users\USER123*:

```
MKLINK /J C:\utilisateurs\USER123 C:\users\USER123
```

Comment: Tested locally. And it works. Going to test on the target laptop later on.

Comment: The right cook is:``c:\`` ; ``cd \`` ; ``MKLINK /J utilisateurs users``

Comment: I see, seems like your tool was only referencing the `utilisateurs` folder, not the `utilisateurs\user123`. And I suppose it's smart to start making links from the very top of the directories. It's strange that explorer knew about the link, but your tool did not. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the MKLINK command to create a junction.
I too need to use this sometimes to make stubborn programs behave.

In your case, it would be this:
`MKLINK /J c:\users\USER123 c:\utilisateurs\USER123`

*Note: You must first create the c:\utilisateurs directory if it does not exist or you will receive error "The system cannot find the path specified."*

You might even just try linking c:\users to c:\utilisateurs

I DO NOT run a localized version of windows so I am giving you the specific answer you asked for.  I am not sure that it will work for you.